# How to define a matrix with all zero elements in python?

Tags: python, matrix

Wanna define a matrix where all elements should be zero. How can I do this?

Comment: Many people use [numpy.zeros](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html) for this if they are doing anything serious with matrices. With pure python I think you are left with list comprehensions and/or loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the zeros function in numpy as:

```
import numpy as np

b = np.zeros((2,1)) # numpy.zeros(shape, dtype = None, order = 'C')
print(b)
```

**Output**

```
[[0.]
 [0.]]
```